# Symfony save partial information in cache

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.3, symfony-cache

With Symfony, I want to use [Cache Manager](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/cache.html) (FilesystemCache) for save my entities. I did this :

```
    $find = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)
        ->getSingleResult([
            'whereId' => $id,
        ]);

    dump($find); // First dump()
    $this->cacheManager->set('user-1', $find);
    dump($this->cacheManager->get('user-1')); // Second dump()
```

**First dump :**

```
User {#457 ▼
    -id: 1
    -username: "contact@site.com"
    -email: "contact@site.com"
    -plainPassword: null
    -password: "$2y$13$sFSRu2lyDmrfFZP24vkeQOiaYJ5E2eo/kLlaIITgwTrwZunEBcO1q"
    -onlineAt: DateTime {#432 ▶}
    -changePasswordAt: null
    -roles: array:3 [▶]
    -registerToken: null
    -versions: PersistentCollection {#558 ▶}
    -deletedAt: null
    -deletedBy: null
}
```

**Second dump :**

```
User {#188 ▼
    -id: 1
    -username: "contact@site.com"
    -email: null
    -plainPassword: null
    -password: "$2y$13$sFSRu2lyDmrfFZP24vkeQOiaYJ5E2eo/kLlaIITgwTrwZunEBcO1q"
    -onlineAt: null
    -changePasswordAt: null
    -roles: []
    -registerToken: null
    -versions: null
    -deletedAt: null
    -deletedBy: null
}
```

Why my second *dump()* does not have all the informations ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to save an object in the cache it has to be [Serializable](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.serializable.php) to tell PHP which properties should be safed, and which not. For comparison you can look how [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Model/User.php#L132-L173) does it.

With larger object graphs (objects and their relationships, such as your `versions` property) it's usually not feasible to have all the information stored in cache as this might cause memory-problems when serializing/unserializing the data. For this Symfony's [UserProvider](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/UserProviderInterface.php#L64) has a `refreshUser()` method which reloads the remaining data. So if you want to cache the data as part of your user management, I suggest you implement this method to make sure the remaining data is fetched whenever this method is called.